# Performing calculations on multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimentional arrays like shown below with same structure, but different values.

```
$first = array (
  'something1' => 
  array (
    '2019-06-14' => 0,
    '2019-06-13' => 0,
    '2019-06-12' => 0,
    '2019-06-11' => 1,
    '2019-06-10' => 1
  ),
  'something2' => 
  array (
    '2019-06-14' => 0,
    '2019-06-13' => 0,
    '2019-06-12' => 0,
    '2019-06-11' => 1,
    '2019-06-10' => 0
  ),
)

$second = array (
  'something1' => 
  array (
    '2019-06-14' => 8,
    '2019-06-13' => 4,
    '2019-06-12' => 7,
    '2019-06-11' => 2,
    '2019-06-10' => 9
  ),
  'something2' => 
  array (
    '2019-06-14' => 3,
    '2019-06-13' => 7,
    '2019-06-12' => 3,
    '2019-06-11' => 4,
    '2019-06-10' => 8
  ),
)
```

I need to perform simple calculation on both, where the result will be like this (value from $first array/value from $second array for each date):

```
$result = array (
  'someting1' => 
  array (
    '2019-06-14' => 0/8,
    '2019-06-13' => 0/4,
    '2019-06-12' => 0/7,
    '2019-06-11' => 1/2,
    '2019-06-10' => 1/9
  ),
  'something2' => 
  array (
    '2019-06-14' => 0/3,
    '2019-06-13' => 0/7,
    '2019-06-12' => 0/3,
    '2019-06-11' => 1/4,
    '2019-06-10' => 0/8
  ),
)
```

I have tried using nested foreach loops and I can display values that I need like shown below, but when i nest another set of foreach loops there for second array it obviously creates too many results dividing everything by everything.

```
foreach($array1 as $sth => $v) {
    foreach($v as $date => $number) {
        echo $sth. ' data: ' . $date . ' number: ' . $number . '</br>';
    }
}
```

How can I perform such calculation?

Comment: Are those are float or strings? (The 0 / 9)

Comment: You don't need any additional loops for the second array; you have the keys `$sth` and `$date` so you can access the values directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple foreach loop should do it:

```
foreach($first as $k => $arr) 
    foreach($arr as $date => $num)
        $result[$k][$date] = $num . " / " . $second[$k][$date];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any additional loops for the second array; you have the keys `$sth` and `$date` so you can access the values directly:

```
foreach($array1 as $sth => $v) {
    foreach($v as $date => $number) {
        echo $sth. ' data: ' . $date . ' number: ' . $number . '</br>';
        echo 'second number: ' . $second[$sth][$date] . '</br>';
    }
}
```

Note that you might need to add checks to see if the keys actually exist in the second array.